# Derivative of a definite integral with respect to a function inside the integral.

Tags: integration, derivatives, integral-equations

Suppose I want to optimise the function
$$f\mapsto \int_\mathbb{R}e^{f(x)}\mathrm{d}x$$
with respect to $f$, where $f$ is concave and twice continuously differentiable. Is there some result that allows me to do this? Perhaps with some additional conditions on $f$? (E.g., only consider functions $f$ such that $f(x) \leq M$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and some $M \in (0,\infty)$).

Since the integral is with respect to $x$ and not $f$, I cannot use the fundamental theorem of calculus, and since the optimisation is over a function space I cannot use the Leibniz integral rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without constraints such as $f\le M$, this is a problem in the [calculus of variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations#Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation). It has Lagrangian $e^f$ and Euler-Lagrange equation $e^f=0$, with no solution (unless you count $f=-\infty$, but given your stated conditions it sounds like you don't).

This is not surprising at all. For example, the choice $f=-kx^2$ makes the integral $\sqrt{\pi/k}$, which no finite $k>0$ minimizes. But the result can be made arbitrarily close to $0$, which is clearly unobtainable for $f>-\infty$.

Similarly, any finite constant $f$ makes the integral infinite, so we can't give the integral a finite maximum even with the constraints you propose.

Comment: That all makes sense. And if I wanted to just compute its derivative with respect to $f$, is that possible? Would it be equal to $e^f(x))$? Or if I add some function of $f$, so I optimise, say $f\mapsto \log(f(x)) + \int e^{f(x)}\mathrm{d}x$? In this case I could not write $\log(f)$ as an integral, and the Euler Lagrange equation is not applicable.

Comment: @Ponky You've used $x$ as both a free variable in $\ln f(x)$ and a bound variable in $\int e^{f(x)}dx$, so let's say you want to see where $\ln f(x)+\int e^{f(x^\prime)}dx^\prime$ is stationary instead, and then you just need to write it as $\int\left[\delta(x^\prime-x)\ln f(x^\prime)+e^{f(x^\prime)}\right]dx^\prime$. ([This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) is worth reading.)

Comment: Oh, yes! Of course, my mistake. Thank you for the reference. I'll have a read.